# IIS configurations issue

Tags: iis-7

We are setting up a website with secure and non secure pages. These have been added for mapping in uriworker.properties. The domain name in the urls are different . Example nonsecure url is x-y-z.a.b.org and our secure url is x-y-secure-z.a.b.org.Both of these domains are part of our DNS entry. We do not have any redirect rules configured within the webserver. But when we try to access the secure url https://x-y-secure-z.a.b.org, webserver is sending the request as **http**://x-y-secure-z.a.b.org:**443**. Due to the scheme not being https , the application does not identify this as secure request and is returning a 302 to the https url. This redirection happens infinitely and then an error appears which says that page is not redirecting properly.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of analysis , we figured out that the application had a hardcoded check on the scheme of the domain name to be in a certain format as secure.xyz.